# Android string with null

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with this code

```
if ((equip != null) && equip.trim().equals("")){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_equip);
```

And my else is

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```

So if my string is null or empty i use this dialog
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
Otherwise i use this one
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_equip);

My logcat gives me this output from this code

```
String equip = reserveComp.getString(TAG_EQUIP);
                        Log.d("Equip", equip);
```

D/Equip﹕ Projetor, so it open the

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```

but when i have this output
D/Equip﹕ null it open the same

So whats wrong?

UPDATE

This is my full block code

```
JSONObject reserveComp = reqFeitasDetail.getJSONObject(0);
                        String equip = reserveComp.getString(TAG_EQUIP);
                        Log.d("Equip", equip);
                        if ((equip == null) || equip.trim().equals("")){
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                            dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                            dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                            dialog.show();
                            Button img = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_button);
                            TextView data = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.data);
                            TextView sala = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sala);
                            TextView hora = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.hora_inicial);
                            TextView fim = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.hora_final);
                            data.setText(reserveComp.getString(TAG_DATA));
                            sala.setText(reserveComp.getString(TAG_NOME));
                            hora.setText(reserveComp.getString(TAG_TEMPO));
                            fim.setText(reserveComp.getString(TAG_TEMPOFIM));
                            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                            dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                            dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_equip);
                            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                            dialog.show();
                            Button img = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_button);
                            TextView data = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.data);
                            TextView sala = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sala);
                            TextView equipamento = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.equip);
                            TextView hora = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.hora_inicial);
                            TextView fim = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.hora_final);
                            data.setText(reserveComp.getString(TAG_DATA));
                            sala.setText(reserveComp.getString(TAG_NOME));
                            equipamento.setText(reserveComp.getString(TAG_EQUIP));
                            hora.setText(reserveComp.getString(TAG_TEMPO));
                            fim.setText(reserveComp.getString(TAG_TEMPOFIM));
                            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

And i had this logcat output

```
D/Reserva Sala completa﹕ {"tag":"reqEquipFull","success":1,"error":0,"reqEquipFull":[{"data":"2015-06-12","sala":"21","inicio":"14:05:00","fim":"15:45:00","nome":null}]}
```

D/Equip﹕ null

And i still have the same problem with the dialog, all (null and non null) open this dialog

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_equip);
```

Comment: To test if ``equip`` is empty you can use :
``if(TextUtils.isEmpty(equip))``

Comment: not working...i have null

Answer (score 4):

To check if your string is null **or** empty, the condition inside the if block should be

```
if ((equip == null) || equip.trim().equals("")){...}
```

You should also switch the code blocks inside your if-else statement if you want to do the following..

> So if my string is null or empty i use this dialog dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout); Otherwise i use this one dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_equip);

```
if ((equip == null) || equip.trim().equals("")){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
}
else {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_equip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the and condition to or condition in if statement

```
if ((equip != null) && equip.trim().equals(""))
```

to

```
if ((equip != null) || equip.trim().equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `AND` condition will never be `true`, you are checking `NOT NULL` in your if statement!!

```
if ((equip != null) && equip.trim().equals("")){
```

Should be an `or` and if `==` null

```
if (equip == null || equip.trim().equals("")){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_equip);
} else {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (equip.equals("null") || equip.isEmpty())
```